# Stable Diffusion, Error loading script: hook.py

Tags: python, runtime-error, stable-diffusion

Seemingly out of nowhere my Stable Diffusion launcher has gotten an issue where it can't load a script.
The program seems to work as intended aside from that so I'm unsure of the impact, but I'd rather get it fixed than it being a problem down the line.

the following is the full cmd log of what happens on launch:

```
venv "C:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
Python 3.10.0 (tags/v3.10.0:b494f59, Oct  4 2021, 19:00:18) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
Version: v1.5.1-55-g25004d4e
Commit hash: 25004d4eeef015d8f886c537d3a5a9f54d07898e

Launching Web UI with arguments: --xformers --autolaunch --no-half-vae
*** Error loading script: hook.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\scripts.py", line 319, in load_scripts
        script_module = script_loading.load_module(scriptfile.path)
      File "C:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\script_loading.py", line 10, in load_module
        module_spec.loader.exec_module(module)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\scripts\hook.py", line 10, in <module>
        from scripts.logging import logger
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.logging'

---
2023-07-31 09:05:07,850 - ControlNet - INFO - ControlNet v1.1.234
ControlNet preprocessor location: C:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\extensions\sd-webui-controlnet\annotator\downloads
2023-07-31 09:05:07,996 - ControlNet - INFO - ControlNet v1.1.234
Loading weights [445ffb5195] from C:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\models\Stable-diffusion\epicrealism_pureEvolutionV4.safetensors
Creating model from config: C:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\configs\v1-inference.yaml
LatentDiffusion: Running in eps-prediction mode
Running on local URL:  http://127.0.0.1:7860

To create a public link, set `share=True` in `launch()`.
DiffusionWrapper has 859.52 M params.
Startup time: 17.7s (prepare environment: 5.4s, launcher: 0.5s, import torch: 3.9s, import gradio: 1.6s, setup paths: 1.9s, other imports: 1.8s, setup codeformer: 0.1s, list SD models: 0.2s, load scripts: 1.4s, scripts before_ui_callback: 0.2s, create ui: 0.4s, gradio launch: 0.4s).
Applying attention optimization: xformers... done.
Model loaded in 7.4s (load weights from disk: 0.8s, create model: 0.7s, apply weights to model: 3.9s, apply half(): 0.5s, move model to device: 1.3s).
```

As you can see, immediately upon launching the program the same way I have done before, I now get met with

```
*** Error loading script: hook.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\scripts.py", line 319, in load_scripts
        script_module = script_loading.load_module(scriptfile.path)
      File "C:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\script_loading.py", line 10, in load_module
        module_spec.loader.exec_module(module)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\Stable Diffusion\stable-diffusion-webui\scripts\hook.py", line 10, in <module>
        from scripts.logging import logger
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts.logging'
```

I have tried doing a fresh install of Python, yet this still occurs, I have even tried a fresh reinstall of the program itself, same problem.

I want to know if anyone who has either used this program or who are proficient enough with Python could help me on how to proceed with repairing this issue?

What I tried:
I simply launched the program using the provided .bat file for initiating the script, same way as I have always done it.

What I expected:
a clean cmd launch log without any error messages

What happened:
I was met with an error message that wasn't there before.

Comment: Could you verify that there is indeed a file called `logging` in `scripts`?

Comment: I checked and there isn't one, I managed to get in contact with the created of the launcher I use and according to them there shouldn't even be a script.py file to begin with.

I don't know why and how that happened, but simply getting rid of the files mentioned in the error message seems to have fixed it.

Sorry for making a useless post

Comment: Interesting. I assume [this](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/issues/12200) is the issue you posted. Just leaving it here as it might be helpful to other users.